# MySQL: why is the date difference always 0?

Tags: mysql

I am practicing my SQL skills, and here's a problem I'm practicing on:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/projects

Here's the problem:

> You are given a table, Projects, containing three columns: Task_ID,
>   Start_Date and End_Date. It is guaranteed that the difference between
>   the End_Date and the Start_Date is equal to 1 day for each row in the
>   table. If the End_Date of the tasks are consecutive, then they are
>   part of the same project. Samantha is interested in finding the total
>   number of different projects completed.
>
> Write a query to output the start and end dates of projects listed by
>   the number of days it took to complete the project in ascending order.
>   If there is more than one project that have the same number of
>   completion days, then order by the start date of the project.

My logic is that, I'll order everything by start date, and then assign rankings to each row. If the current end date is consecutive from previous end date, aka datediff(end_date, @e) = 1, then I'll keep the same ranking number, else I'll increment the ranking by 1. So then basically all the rows belonging to the same project will have the same ranking.

Below is my code:

```
set @r := 0;
select min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select start_date, end_date, 
      @r := if(datediff(end_date, @e) = 1, @r, @r+1) ranking,
      @e := end_date
      from projects
      order by start_date
     ) b
group by ranking
order by datediff(max(end_date), min(start_date)), 1
;
```

But this code is not working.

**Update**

After making changes according to Sasha Pachev's answer, when I tried to check the subquery:

```
set @r = 0;
select start_date, end_date, 
@e := end_date, datediff(end_date, date(@e)),
@r := if(datediff(end_date, date(@e)), @r, @r+1) ranking
from projects
order by start_date
;
```

I noticed that all my date diff are 0:

```
2015-10-01 2015-10-02 2015-10-02 0 1 
2015-10-02 2015-10-03 2015-10-03 0 2 
2015-10-03 2015-10-04 2015-10-04 0 3 
2015-10-04 2015-10-05 2015-10-05 0 4 
2015-10-11 2015-10-12 2015-10-12 0 5 
2015-10-12 2015-10-13 2015-10-13 0 6 
2015-10-15 2015-10-16 2015-10-16 0 7 
2015-10-17 2015-10-18 2015-10-18 0 8 
2015-10-19 2015-10-20 2015-10-20 0 9
```

And I understand why, because I assigned the @e as the end date before assigning ranking @r. But if I assign @e after @r, it doesnt work since I need @e to have a value for the diffdate() function. 
Can someone help me break this cycle?

Comment: Can you try explicitly casting the date to the DATETIME type? It may be that they are stored as VARCHAR and can't be implicitly casted.

Comment: Hi @Sinfieldd, thanks for the suggestion! I did try to use "Date(@e)" in my subquery testing code. It's not working properly. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT         START_DATE, MIN(END_DATE) AS [END_DATE]
    FROM       (
                    (SELECT         START_DATE 
                            FROM    PROJECTS 
                            WHERE   START_DATE NOT IN (SELECT END_DATE FROM PROJECTS)
                    ) A
                    CROSS JOIN
                    (SELECT        END_DATE 
                            FROM   PROJECTS 
                            WHERE  END_DATE NOT IN (SELECT START_DATE FROM PROJECTS)
                    ) B
               )     
    WHERE      START_DATE < END_DATE
    GROUP BY   START_DATE
    ORDER BY   DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(END_DATE), START_DATE) DESC, CAST(START_DATE AS DATE) ASC
```

Comment: Some description about what you are trying to do will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The order of assignment/use of user variables matters. Try:

```
select start_date, end_date,@e := end_date, datediff(end_date, date(@e)),
      @r := if(end_date-@e = 1, @r, @r+1) ranking,

      from projects
      order by start_date
;
```

assigning to `@e` first, and then using it in `datediff()`

Comment: Please see my updated question! thank you soooo much!

Comment: Now you are dealing with your query logic error rather than a MySQL user variables/date issue. The logic in the above test query is not very meaningful as we are taking the difference of `end_date` against itself which will be zero. Did you mean to use `start_date` ?

Comment: Hi Sasha, no i'm not trying to use start_date. as the problem states, if the end dates are consecutive, then it's considered to belong to the same project, hence i'm comparing the end_dates only. I'm not sure where my logic went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sasha Pachev for some great suggestions!

Articulating my problems here definitely helped me to think more clearly. I've been stuck on this problem for two days, and now I just reached an epiphany...

I finally understood the root causes of my problem, and have figured out a fix. My biggest problem was that I did not set @e initially, so then when I assign @e before @r, the date difference is always going to be 0! (of course, because it's just subtracting itself). and if I assign @e after @r then it's always NULL.

Below is my code that is working and correct, hopefully this can help someone as well:

```
set @r = 0;
set @e = (select max(end_date) from projects);
select min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (
    select start_date, end_date, 
    @r := if(datediff(end_date, date(@e)) = 1, @r, @r+1) ranking,
    @e := end_date
    from projects
    order by start_date
    ) b
group by ranking
order by datediff(max(end_date), min(start_date)), 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a query like this. you can do the init of the vars direct in the query:

```
SELECT min(start_date), max(end_date)
FROM (select start_date, end_date, 
      @r := if(datediff(end_date, @e) = 1, @r, @r+1) ranking,
      @e := end_date as ee
      FROM projects
      CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @r:=0, @e:='1970-01-01') as init
      ORDER BY start_date
     ) b
GROUP BY ranking
ORDER BY datediff(max(end_date), min(start_date));
```

**sample output**

```
2015-10-15 2015-10-16 
2015-10-17 2015-10-18 
2015-10-19 2015-10-20 
2015-10-21 2015-10-22 
2015-11-01 2015-11-02 
2015-11-17 2015-11-18 
2015-10-11 2015-10-13 
2015-11-11 2015-11-13 
2015-10-01 2015-10-05 
2015-11-04 2015-11-08 
2015-10-25 2015-10-31
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, thanks so much for the help! I was wondering why are you doing a cross join?

Comment: Hi @alwaysaskingquestions, the **CROSS JOIN** is only to do something before the query runs (init the vars) and it runs only one time. so its only a easy way for the init and you have one query less to execute

Comment: and at last. in your query you not initialize @e

Comment: so you initialized @e to 1970-01-01, is that an arbitrary date that you just picked?

Comment: you can init @e to what ever you want. NULL or '' so that the if at the first row generate a @r+1. If you run the query second time from the same connection without init the last val is in @e and can give a wrong result

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT SD,ED
FROM
(SELECT MIN(START_DATE) SD, MAX(END_DATE) ED, ( MAX(END_DATE)-MIN(START_DATE)) dd
FROM
(
SELECT  START_DATE, END_DATE, END_DATE - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY END_DATE) DIST
FROM PROJECTS
 ORDER BY 1)
GROUP BY DIST
 ORDER BY 3,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Start_Date, min(End_Date)
FROM 
 (SELECT Start_Date FROM Projects WHERE Start_Date NOT IN (SELECT End_Date FROM Projects)) a ,
 (SELECT End_Date FROM Projects WHERE End_Date NOT IN (SELECT Start_Date FROM Projects)) b
WHERE Start_Date < End_Date
GROUP BY Start_Date
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(min(End_Date), Start_Date) ASC, Start_Date ASC;
```

Comment: The question was "MySQL: why is the date difference always 0?", so a code-only answer can't be a considered a complete answer to the question. [Including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Below is my Solution */


select Min_Start_Date,Max_End_Date
from (
select distinct 
       min(start_date) over (partition by Ref_Start_date) as Min_Start_Date,
       max(End_Date) over (Partition by Ref_End_Date) as Max_End_Date,
       count(*) over (partition by Ref_Start_date,Ref_End_Date) as CNT
from (
        select 
        start_date,
        start_date+dense_rank() over (order by start_date desc) as Ref_Start_date, 
        end_date,
        End_date+dense_rank() over (order by End_date desc) as Ref_End_date
        from projects
    )
 order by 3,1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it with a help of while loop and using temp table

```
select * , row_number() over (order by start_date) rn into #temp 
from projects
order by start_date

declare @counter int = 2
declare @e_date date = (select min(end_date) from #temp)

while @counter <= (select max(rn) from #temp)
begin
    if @e_date = (select start_date from #temp where rn = @counter)
    begin
        update #temp
        set start_date = (select start_date from #temp where rn = @counter -1 )
        where rn = @counter

        delete from #temp
        where rn = @counter - 1

        set @e_date = (select end_date from #temp where rn = @counter)
    end
else
    begin
        set @e_date = (select end_date from #temp where rn = @counter)
    end

     set @counter = @counter + 1
end


select start_date , end_date from #temp
order by datediff(day , start_date , end_date) , start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Min_Start_Date,Max_End_Date

from (

select distinct
 
       min(start_date) over (partition by Ref_Start_date) as Min_Start_Date,

       max(End_Date) over (Partition by Ref_End_Date) as Max_End_Date,

       count(*) over (partition by Ref_Start_date,Ref_End_Date) as CNT

from (

        select 

        start_date,

        start_date+dense_rank() over (order by start_date desc) as Ref_Start_date, 

        end_date,

        End_date+dense_rank() over (order by End_date desc) as Ref_End_date

        from projects

    )

 order by 3,1
);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
select start_Date,end_date from (
select start_Date,end_date,datediff(day,start_Date,end_date)as diff1 from 
(
select start_Date,row_number() over (order by start_Date) as rn from
(select start_date from projects
where start_date not in (select distinct end_date from projects)
) t1)t1a

left join 
(select end_date,row_number() over (order by end_date) as rn from
(select end_date from projects
where end_date not in (select distinct start_date from projects)
) t2)t2a

on t1a.rn=t2a.rn )tx
order by diff1 , start_date
```